# Unity - function behave unexpectedly inside a coroutine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

the function look like this:

```cs
private void Shrink(Animation anim)
{
    AnimationClip clip = new AnimationClip();
    clip.legacy = true;

    char[] c = { 'x', 'y', 'z' };
    float rot = Random.value * 360 - 180;
    Vector3 toPosition = transform.position + (Random.value * radius * 5 / 6 + radius / 6) * new Vector3(Mathf.Cos(rot), Mathf.Sin(rot));
    float scaleMul = Random.value / 4 + 1.0f / 2.0f;
    float duration = (transform.position - toPosition).magnitude / speed;
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Keyframe[] keys;
        keys = new Keyframe[2];
        keys[0] = new Keyframe(0.0f, transform.position[i]);
        keys[1] = new Keyframe(duration, toPosition[i]);
        curve = new AnimationCurve(keys);
        clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localPosition." + c[i], curve);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        Keyframe[] keys;
        keys = new Keyframe[2];
        keys[0] = new Keyframe(0.0f, transform.localScale[i]);
        keys[1] = new Keyframe(duration, transform.localScale[i] * scaleMul);
        curve = new AnimationCurve(keys);
        clip.SetCurve("", typeof(Transform), "localScale." + c[i], curve);
    }


    // now animate the GameObject
    anim.AddClip(clip, clip.name);
    anim.Play(clip.name);
}
```

all it does is that it sort of animate the shrinking of a border and moving it to some random location inside a radius. the function works fine if I call it on its own but I want the function to be called every x seconds so I wrote this coroutine:

```cs
IEnumerator ShrinkCR(float time)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(time);

        Shrink(anim);
    }
}
```

and simply called it inside update():

```cs
private void Update()
{
    StartCoroutine(ShrinkCR(10));
}
```

but when I do that the border goes crazy and instead going to some random location inside some radius it just accelerate to the right indefinitly. What did I do wrong????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Update` is called every frame, so you are launching th corroutine 60 times per second approx. That is why you are getting that behaviour. Call it once wherever/whenever you need, not in the update.

Comment: that doesn't make sense. I thought coroutines are designed to run under update.

Comment: I think it makes sense. As most of things, they run when called :)

Comment: @DarQ to be exact Coroutines are basically small little temporary `Update` methods (this is over simplified of course). Each `Update` call the Coroutine will be executed until the next `yield` statement. A `yield return new WaitForSeconds (1);` basically equals using `var time = 0; while(time  < 1){ time += Time.deltaTime; yield return null; }`

Comment: nvm, it works. so if I understand this correctly, the coroutine runs separately from the function it runs in. during its run it halts the function it ran in, does its thing that frame and can then return control in the yield statement?